# ¿Cómo llamar al ID de la variable que estoy iterando en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Estoy trabajando con *Laravel* haciendo un CRUD y para el método PATCH estoy teniendo problemas. Estoy pasando 2 parámetros desde mi controlador, en uno tengo almacenadas unas respuestas de preguntas en un array (**El parámetro que le paso se llama *$proyecto* y dentro esta el campo preguntas $proyecto->preguntas**)

Y le paso otro parámetro llamado *$DATA2* que es donde están almacenadas las preguntas.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se imprima la pregunta 1 se imprima igual la respuesta de la pregunta número 1 y así sucesivamente.

Pero en lugar de eso lo que se imprime es la pregunta 1 y todas las respuestas de las preguntas, y en la pregunta 2 vuelven a imprimir las respuestas de todas las preguntas.

Controlador:

```
//Formulario para editar usuarios
public function editform($id){
    $proyecto = Project::findOrFail($id);

    $data2= Questions::all();

    return view('layouts.projects.editProject',  compact('data2') ,compact('proyecto'));
}

//Edición de usuarios
public function edit(Request $request, $id){
    
    $request->merge([ 
        'Areas' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('Areas')),
        'preguntas' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('preguntas'))
        ]);


    $datosProyecto = request()->except((['_token', '_method']));
    Project::where('id', '=', $id)->update($datosProyecto);


    return  view('layouts.projects.editProject')->with('proyectoModificado','Proyecto Modificado');
}
```

Esta es la vista donde quiero imprimir esos datos:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-12 mt-5'>";

    echo "<label for=''>" . $row["pre"] . "&&" . $row["id"] . "</label>";

    $a = explode(',', $proyecto->preguntas);

    echo "<input type='text' name='preguntas[]' class='form-control col-12' value= '$a[0]'  > ";

    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De momento lo resolvi haciendo un Explode() en las respuestas de las preguntas y posteriormente cree una variable fuera del ciclo while que sea autoincremente y pase esa variable como parametro dentro de value='$porciones......'

```
 $var = 0;
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo "<div class='col-md-12 mt-5'>";

                    echo "<label for=''>" . $row["pre"] ."</label>";

                    $a = $proyecto->preguntas;

                    $pizza  = $proyecto->preguntas;
                    $porciones = explode(",", $pizza);

                    echo "<input type='text' name='preguntas[]' class='form-control col-12' value= $porciones[$var] > ";

                    echo "</div>";
                    $var++;
                }
```